# Llamar una variable no static en un método static

Tags: java

Comprendo que en un método `static` no se puede llamar a una variable que no sea `static`. Pero, ¿por qué no se puede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables `static`y los métodos `static` están en el nivel de clase. Variables y métodos que están en ese nivel son resueltos por el intérprete antes que las variables y los métodos instanciados (los que no son `static`).

Obviamente no puedes tratar de usar algo que no ha sido resuelto por el intérprete. El compilador de Java no dejará que eso sea resuelto en tiempo de ejecución. Por eso es que te sale el error `non-static things can not be referred from static context.`

Los temas que debes leer para profundizar más en esto son `Class Level Scope`, `Instance Level Scope` y `Local Scope`. Todo eso está [aquí (en inglés)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) o lo puedes buscar en google para encontrar los temas en español.

Answer (score 1):

Una clase es una pauta para objetos de un tipo. Métodos y variables de la clase son de esta pauta, te lo puedes imaginar como un prototipo. Aun que todos objetos instados están basados en esta pauta, la pauta esta agnóstica de los objetos que se crean "en su imagen".

Variables de la instancia ni siquiera existen sin instar el objeto primero. Un ejemplo: tenemos la Clase `Extraterreste`:

```
public class Extraterrestre{
    
    public static final int PIEL_AZUL=0;
    public static final int PIEL_VERDE=1;
    public static final int PIEL_ROJO=2;

    public int colorDePiel;
    public String especies;

    public Extraterrestre(String especie, int color){
        this.especie=especie;
        this.colorDePiel=color;
    }

    public boolean esAzul(){
        return (colorDePiel==PIEL_AZUL);
    }

    public boolean esVerde(){
        return (colorDePiel==PIEL_VERDE);
    }

    public boolean esRojo(){
        return (colorDePiel==PIEL_ROJO);
    }
}
```

Un Extraterrestre es un abstracto, sin tener uno concreto, no se puede saber que color tiene. Pero según nuestra clase sabemos que puede ser azul, verde o rojo.

```
Extraterestre fulanito = new Extraterrestre("Marsiano", Extraterrestre.PIEL_ROJO);
System.out.println(fulanito.esRojo());

true
```

De fulanito sabemos que fulanito es marsiano, y que su piel es rojo. Porque fulanito es un objeto unico, podemos acceder a sus atributos `especies` y `colorDePiel`.

[¡No temas la POO!](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/jon/family/jos/oop_es/oop1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No se puede ya que un metodo static se puede ejecutar sin instanciar la Clase que contiene al metodo , mientras que un miembro no static(miembros de instancia) solo estan disponibles luego de que la clase es instanciada.

Es un tema de alcance (Scope).